# FOR /F error not reading .csv {BATCH FILE}

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv, windows-xp

i am currently getting these errors when running my batch file:

```
System error 1379 has occurred.

The specified local group already exists.

Press any key to continue . . .
The system cannot find the file users.csv. {This is where my problem lies}
Press any key to continue . . .
There is no such global user or group: users.csv
```

My Batch File

```
@echo off

REM Adding a local group
net localgroup NEWDOSGROUP /Comment:"New Group Assignment" /add
pause
REM Add all the users from a .csv file

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (users.csv) DO (
    net adduser

pause
REM Adding users to a local group
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN ("users.csv") Do (
    net localgroup NEWDOSGROUP %%a /add
    )
pause
```

any help would be amazing thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put `users.csv` in the same folder as the batch file.

This loop is also missing a closing parenthesis by the look of it, and the net adduser should probably have an argument of %%G or %%H or similar

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (users.csv) DO (
    net adduser
```

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (users.csv) DO (net adduser %%G %%H)
tried this still comes up with system cannot find file even though it is in the same directory?

Comment: `FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (users.csv) DO echo %%G %%H` <-- try that and make sure the file has the same name as it says there `users.csv` and triple check it.

Comment: ive triple checked and even with that command is still says 
The system cannot find the file users.csv.

Comment: If you are elevating the permissions when running the batch file then the working directory changes to c:\windows\system32 usually.  In that case you will have to add a `cd /d "c:\folder\here\"` command at the start of the batch file with the folder in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
REM Add all the users from a .csv file

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (users.csv) DO (
    net adduser

REM ARE YOU MISSING A CLOSE-PARENTHESIS HERE?
REM WHAT IS NET ADDUSER?
REM WHY ARE YOU NOT USING %%G,%%H?
REM HERE YOU'VE OPENED USERS.CSV... ARE YOU THEN TRYING TO RE-OPEN IT?
REM IS AN OPEN USERS.CSV CAUSING THE PROBLEM?
REM IS THE SYNTAX OF THE FOR...%%a CORRECT? USEBACKQ PERHAPS?
REM NOT SHOUTING - JUST EMPHASISING

pause
REM Adding users to a local group
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN ("users.csv") Do (
    net localgroup NEWDOSGROUP %%a /add
    )
pause
```